# why different result of same xml only with border?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I use following xml, it works on most device , but in some devices the background is not trasparent, is black? why and how solve?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape>

            <stroke android:width="@dimen/_3sdp" android:color="#dcdcdc" />
            <corners android:radius="@dimen/_10sdp" />
            <padding android:bottom="@dimen/_6sdp" android:left="@dimen/_6sdp" android:right="@dimen/_6sdp" android:top="@dimen/_6sdp" />


        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

The result must be like this :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your above xml border, you've only specified the color of shape. You didn't mention the color of background. You can set solid background color as Transparent inside shape tag:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

 <item>
    <shape>

        <stroke android:width="@dimen/_3sdp" android:color="#dcdcdc" />
        <corners android:radius="@dimen/_10sdp" />
        <padding android:bottom="@dimen/_6sdp" android:left="@dimen/_6sdp" android:right="@dimen/_6sdp" android:top="@dimen/_6sdp" />

         <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />    <!-- Add This -->

    </shape>
</item>
```

Hope this helps.